# Typescript compiler omits a "non assignable" error for tuples

Tags: typescript, tuples, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

Having the following code:

```
var abc: [string, number] = [5, "test"];

console.log(abc);
```

The red squiggly line, as I expected, appears under 'abc', with this error:

> [ts] Type '[number, string]' is not assignable to type '[string,
>   number]'.
>          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

However, it still compiles it into JS like this:

```
var abc = [5, "test"];
console.log(abc);
```

Did I miss some compiler option, or it is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard TypeScript behavior.  For most types of errors, the TypeScript compiler still generates a JavaScript file.  (It does return a non-zero exit code that build scripts can detect and act on.)

Try out some other types of errors, like mistyped variable names:

```
var abc: number = 5;
console.log(abd);
```

and you'll see the same thing happen.

Edit: oh, and there *is* a compiler flag to change this behavior.  Using:

```
tsc --noEmitOnError test.ts
```

will suppress generating the test.js file if errors are encountered.